# what i am asking is, how to handle that binderresult error my custom error that : **Pincode cannot be empty**

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation

Pincode validator class

public class PincodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator {
    int size;

```
@Override
public void initialize(IsValidPincode constraintAnnotation) {
    this.size = constraintAnnotation.sizeOfPincode();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Integer num, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {

    if(num==null)return false;
    if(Math.floor(Math.log10(num) + 1)==size) return true;
    return false;
}}
```

**Student Bean column :**

```
@IsValidPincode(sizeOfPincode=6, message="Pincode must be of size {sizeOfPincode}")
@Column(name="pincode")
int pincode;
```

**Error given by BinderResult:**

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property pincode; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

what i am asking is, how to handle that binderresult error my custom error that :
**Pincode cannot be empty**

Comment: Use `Integer pincode` rather than `int pincode`

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt already did that, thanks

Comment: Did that solve the problem? If not, edit the question to reflect the change

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt yes solved, thanks allot